# Get images along route with Google street view?

Tags: android, google-street-view

I've been experimenting with the Google static street view [api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro) and it works great. Just one question: Is there any way to get all the images along a route? So I would have a set of images as if one was walking down that street? I would think there would be references to the connecting images in the metadata of a single image but I can't find anything.

I'll be attempting to use this in an android app.

Comment: RadHatter, what do you mean with "connecting (up and down the street)"? Do you mean images taken from one point, looking in different directions? Or do you mean images of a certain route (showing let's say one picture every x meters)?